# Multiple prefix tags in rpm spec file

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I have an rpm that builds two packages. I tried to add separate Prefix tags in the preamble each of the packages.

However, as there is one prep section, I am not able to address the prefix each of the packages individually. (%prefix indicates only the Prefix of the subpackage)

Is there a way to specify package-specific prefix?

Comment: `%packagename-prefix` ?

Comment: that didn't work for me!

Answer (score 1):

Use macros like {%prefix1} to name multiple prefixes and then use syntax like "Prefix: %{prefix1}". I'm not sure what you are expecting from multiple prefixes in rpm packaging. Prefixes were designed for relocatable packages, but all paths in a *.rpm package can be relocated during install. Adding an explicit Prefix: just disables a warning message.